# JetPack Compose no effect for clickable item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, composable

I have a column with a card in the middle. There should be an action when you click on column, but nothing should happen when you click on the card. (like cancelable dialogs)

When I did this with XML, this problem was solved when set the clickable (true) for the column, but when in Jetpack Compose, when I click on the card, there is an effect that I can not delete it

i set this code to Modifier of Card :

```
.clickable{}
```

how delete default effect(press effect no ripple) from clickable item ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set indication to null to not have ripple when your Composable is clicked

```
Modifier.clickable(
    interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
    indication = null,
    onClick = {}
)
```

#### Edit

Assuming you don' want ripple to move through Card inside Column and to achieve that you can use a `Box` that contains `Column` and `Card` as siblings.

```
   Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(200.dp)
            .background(Color.Green)
            .clickable { },
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Card(
            elevation = 4.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
                    indication = null,
                    onClick = {
                        Toast
                            .makeText(context, "Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                )
        ) {
            Text("In Card")
        }
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.Green)
                .size(200.dp)
                .clickable {
                    Toast
                        .makeText(context, "Column", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                },

            ) {

        }

        Card(
            elevation = 4.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .clickable(
                    interactionSource = MutableInteractionSource(),
                    indication = null,
                    onClick = {
                        Toast
                            .makeText(context, "Card", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    }
                )
        ) {
            Text("In Card")
        }
    }
```

First one is what you have i guess, if you use a Box and add both items you won't see ripple moving inside your Card

First one is what you have
Second one is with Box that won't have ripple in Card

[image]